# Je vous en prie

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

I had this chat with an online french teacher:

Me: Hey! I am interested to be your student. Do you accept an absolute beginner french student?

Him: **Je vous en prie!**

As far as i know (since i am a beginner), "je vous en prie" is a more polite way to say "it's you that i should be thanking." It's used when someone thank you and you want to be more polite than just responding with "you're welcome."

Or it could be any else? Please i need an explanation. Thank you

Comment: I recognize that it looks weird in the way he said it. The basic formula is :  _Merci_  --> _Je vous en prie !_  
So I think in this way, he wanted to say that it would be a pleasure for him to have you as a student, so he said _je vous en prie_ like he would say _Avec plaisir_. But you're right, it has no sense here

Comment: It's close to the enthusiastic "***By all means!***" in English when you are politely agreeing with a suggestion.

Comment: As a native, I have to say that it really sounds weird here... Is your teacher really a native?

Comment: @Sharcoux I'm surprised that you find the teacher's answer weird. *Je vous prie d'être mon étudiant* is quite correct and polite French.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer to "do you accept beginners?" cannot be "Je vous en prie". There is just no way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the time, the expression "Je vous en prie" is an answer when you ask something. It is used mostly after a question beginning by the "**pouvoir**" verb which means "**can**".

For exemple :

- Puis-je prendre du chocolat ? / *Can I take some chocolate ?*
- **Je vous en prie**

So in your case, this is exactly what it means : like a more polite way to say "**OK**".

You can also use "**Je vous en prie**" when you let someone do something. The most common example is on the public transport. When you see an old person and you want to let him/her sit, you would say : "**Asseyez-vous, je vous en prie** / *Please, take a seat*". The use of "**Je vous en prie**" here let the old person know that it doesn't bother you (and that is quite polite).